# Angular run AOT + Rollup compilation with ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, aot

I have following script in my angular2 project, usually when I want to run project the command I use will be ng serve... (start-prod, start-uat, start-dev)

However, after I read about AOT https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#workflow-and-convenience-script I try to follow the step and don't know how to start application because, ng serve is only thing I used at the beginning.

what script should I use to start ?

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-prod": "ng serve --environment=prod --deploy / --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "start-uat": "ng serve  --environment=uat --deploy / --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "start-dev": "ng serve  --environment=dev --deploy / --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "build-prod": "ng build  --environment=prod --aot false output-hashing none --deploy /",
    "build-uat": "ng build  --environment=uat --aot false output-hashing none --deploy /",
    "build-dev": "ng build  --environment=dev --aot false output-hashing none --deploy /",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Also, I want to run AOT with ngc not AOT from web pack, I have issues on using custom decorator https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox and I want to try this build on production

Comment: try this `ng serve --aot`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167600/how-to-use-ahead-of-time-compiler-with-angular-cli-webpack

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
ng build -prod
```

This will create files in your dist folder that will be aot build.

`aot` is by default in prod. so specifying `--aot` doesn't make any effect. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979418/angular-2-aot-vs-jit/42011373#42011373).

Comment: but, I want to run AOT with ngc not AOT from web pack, I have issues on using custom decorator https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

To make your project running you can simply fire `ng serve` or `ng serve --aot` command

Basically at the time of creating build we will use `aot` along with `prod` to minimize the size of your bundle in the production use.

These are the various command provided by angular team you run with `ng` .

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-prod": "ng serve --environment=prod --deploy / --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "start-uat": "ng serve  --environment=uat --deploy / --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "start-dev": "ng serve  --environment=dev --deploy / --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "build-prod": "ng build  --environment=prod --aot false output-hashing none --deploy /",
    "build-uat": "ng build  --environment=uat --aot false output-hashing none --deploy /",
    "build-dev": "ng build  --environment=dev --aot false output-hashing none --deploy /",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

like `ng serve` , `ng serve --aot --prod` etc

Comment: but, I want to run AOT with ngc not AOT from web pack, I have issues on using custom decorator https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox